# Sender name mail in template html with golang

Tags: html, email, templates, go

I want to send email with golang, but I have a problem,

I want to parse the sender name ( ex: Sender ex@mail.com) in template file html because I have multiple template with mail, when I put the email in template file, it doesn't work, it says :

" error: 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax"

Is there another way to put this sender name in html file ? a particular syntax ?

Thank you

Comment: The error message seems to originate from your mail server or program, the email address you provided in an answer below shows an obvious syntax error and the code snippet you provided doesn't even show the sender address parsing. You should try to further pinpoint the problem: Try to send an email with a manually entered sender address, print out the sender address after parsing, consult the documentation for your email sending agent. I'm not even sure why you think the sender address belongs in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this syntax `SenderName <ex@mail.com>`, so wrap the email address in angular brackts. I use this with AWS SES to send emails from C# and always worked like a charm, so maybe is the same with Go

Comment: I already use this syntax SenderName <ex@mail.com> in html file but not working,
This is says bad syntax

Comment: can you post the file as well?

Comment: also which framework/library are you using to send the email with Go? So we can reproduce your issue and investigate more